# `WKWebView` on macOS, missing pointer events (hover, cursor changes, etc.)

Tags: macos, wkwebview, pointer-events

As a test, I put a **`WKWebView`** into an `NSWindow` in a template macOS app. Everything works as expected, except the mouse cursor doesn't change when hovering over hyperlinks, and the corresponding ":hover" pseudo classes (etc.) don't trigger in CSS, etc.

The same page works fine in Safari or Chrome.

How is it possible to restore this functionality when using **`WKWebView`** on a non-touch device?

Comment: I am trying to figure this out right now, did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Thanks for this post. I discovered the same. Me neighter tried out but didn't come up with a solution.